# Transform T4 template that is included in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4

So the problem is that I have a **T4 template** which is contained in **referenced assembly**, I would like to transform that template and apply it to **current solution** files. Currently I am thinking on going for powershell script accessing that assembly and running trasnformText.exe on the file. Any help/ideas appreciated.

Comment: As part of your development, build or releasing? Why can't you copy the T4 template into the current solution? Is the powershell script only going to run locally or on all environments?

Comment: Is the "T4 Template" in the "referenced assembly" a preprocessed text template?

Comment: The T4 template is intended to work as part of a framework, where you only need a reference to .dll and then voila, every time you build, your files are transformed as expected (the template performs transformation of specific attribute decorated class'es). It should be done during Debug builds, the generated files will be checked and used for release. Still this is conceptual assumptions, even T4 is an option and I would be glad to hear more alternatives.